# How to customize Bootstrap Maven WebJar theme in Spring Boot with Thymeleaf and sass-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, sass, bootstrap-5, webjars

I'm working on a Spring Boot project that uses Thymeleaf as the template engine and Bootstrap provided via Maven WebJar. I would like to customize the Bootstrap theme, specifically the colors and other variables, using sass-maven-plugin to compile the SCSS files.

I have already successfully integrated Bootstrap into my project using Maven WebJar, and I can see the Bootstrap SCSS files within the project dependencies. However, I'm unsure how to proceed to modify the colors and other variables of Bootstrap to fit the needs of my project.

Could someone kindly provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to customize the Bootstrap theme using sass-maven-plugin in a Spring Boot project with Thymeleaf?

Thank you in advance for the help!